# Why is the Symfony Mailer Component returning an empty response?

Tags: symfony, components, mailer, zoho, dsn

I want to convert my mailing from Swift Mailer to the Mailer Component, since I upgraded to Symfony 4.3.

I've translated my MAILER_URL to a MAILER_DSN, the following way:

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://smtp.zoho.eu:465?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&username=bar@foo.com&password=password123
MAILER_DSN=smtp://bar@foo.com:password123@smtp.zoho.eu:465/?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login
```

As you can see, I'm using Zoho as my mail provider.

However, I'm getting the following internal server error:

```
Expected response code "250" but got an empty response.
```

I've tried switching from SSL to TLS, with no (different) result.

The code I've written to send my test mail, is as follows:

```
$email = (new TemplatedEmail())
  ->from('bar@foo.com')
  ->to('foo@bar.com')
  ->subject('Test')
  ->htmlTemplate('email.html.twig')
  ->context([
    'expiration_date' => new \DateTime('+7 days'),
    'username' => 'foo',
  ])
;

$this->mailer->send($email);
```

I expect my code to send a mail to "foo@bar.com", but instead it turns the empty response as described.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint (or var_dumping) the parsed DSN inside Symfony Mailer's Transport: https://github.com/symfony/mailer/blob/ca3a1473069c3c14080698d27ab6a30c15701b19/Transport.php#L75 & https://github.com/symfony/mailer/blob/ca3a1473069c3c14080698d27ab6a30c15701b19/Transport.php#L173-L182? Maybe the DSN is not parsed correctly for some reason.

Comment: I can verify that it is parsing correctly. The authentication works, it just returns an empty response for some reason...

Comment: Have you tried using port 587 instead of 465?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the the "@" in the username must be encoded:

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://bar%40foo.com:password123@smtp.zoho.eu:465/?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login
```

Credit to fabpot. Here is the link to his answer https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/32148#issuecomment-517903812